# Text jumping up on smaller resolution

Tags: html, css

Having an issue on my webpage when on a small resolution. (600px width) 
[sim.rgmgleague.com](http://sim.rgmgleague.com/cap/trades.php)

[image]

The text is being all weird when the screen resolution gets smaller, only occurs on some of the entries.

Comment: Post all of your code. It's impossible to guess based off of an image.

Answer (score 0):

You must change your css and html:

```
<div class="entry">
   <h4>August 23, 2016</h4>
   <div class="team1">
      <div class="teambanner1">
         <img class="team_1_logo" src="assets/Anaheim.png">
         <h2 class="team_1_h2">Anaheim Receives</h2>
      </div>
      <h3>2019 Philadelphia 1st</h3>
      <h3>Sean Couturier</h3>
      <h3>James Wisniewski</h3>
      <h3>Pascal Laberge</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="team2">
     <div class="teambanner2">
        <img class="team_2_logo" src="assets/Philadelphia.png">
        <h2 class="team_2_h2">Philadelphia Receives</h2>
     </div>
  <h3>Corey Perry</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.team1 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.team2 {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
.team_1_h2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.team_2_h2 {
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
.team_1_logo, .team_2_logo {
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    float: right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
.teambanner1, .teambanner2 {
    margin-top: -8px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
.team1,team2 {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
}
```

After that you need to match other styles.

The second thing; in some cases div.players is missing (Calgary August 23, 2016).

Also, class "players" should be an unordered list (ul li).